# Unsolvable iterated integral: $\int_0^8\int_{y^{1/3}}^2 4e^{x^4} dx\,dy$

Tags: calculus, integration, multivariable-calculus, iterated-integrals

Having issues solving the following iterated integral, which appears to not have a tangible antiderivative.
$$\int_0^8\int_{y^{1/3}}^2 4e^{x^4} dx\,dy$$

So, I figure it as a graph with the domain of $(x,y): 0≤y≤8, y{^{\frac{1}{3}}≤x≤2}$, making the graph bound by the lines $y=x^3, x=2$, and $y=8$. However, switching the integrals around does not clarify this equation whatsoever. Should I take the ln of the entire function?
Please help.

Comment: Hint: What if you switched the order of integration? You'd need to adjust the limits of integration, but maybe something will happen....

Comment: That's what I was getting at, but you're still left with the integral. The new limits of integral would be 0 to 2 and y^(1/3) to 2 dydx

Comment: Double-check your inner limits of integration.

Answer (score 3):

**HINT:**

$$\int_0^8\int_{y^{\frac{1}{3}}}^2 4e^{x^4} \,dx\,dy=\int_0^2 4e^{x^4}\int_0^{x^3} \,dy\,dx$$

Comment: Hm... so you get the first one as an integral of y?

Comment: The inner inyegral is $\int_0^{x^3}(1)\,dy=x^3$

Answer (score 0):

@Joshua, the key is that you can write the region of integration $A$ in another way.

Here, the $A$ is known $(x, y) : 0 \le y \le 8, \:\: y^{1/3} \le x \le 2 $, now **if you draw the region, you may also find** that it is as same as 
$$ A = (x, y): 0 \le y \le x^{3}, \:\: 0 \le x \le 2  $$

So the iterated integral over $(x, y) : 0 \le y \le 8, \:\: y^{1/3} \le x \le 2 $ is as same as integral over $(x, y): 0 \le y \le x^{3}, \:\: 0 \le x \le 2$ which is

$$ \int_{0}^{x^{3}} \int_{0}^{2} 4e^{x^{4}} dx dy $$
which can be worked on as
$$ \int_{0}^{x^{3}} \int_{0}^{2} 4e^{x^{4}} dx dy =  \int_{0}^{2} \int_{0}^{x^{3}}  4e^{x^{4}} dy dx =    \int_{0}^{2} 4e^{x^{4}} (x^{3} - 0) dx =    4 \int_{0}^{2} x^{3} e^{x^{4}}  dx$$
now use method of substitution $u=...$